# How can I protect and hide the data in a single excel cell using password?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, cells, password-protection

My professor want me to send out an excel sheet which contains grades of all students.
And of course every student can only see his own grade. So he want me to set passwords for the grade cells. Each student will have his own password, and when he click his grade cell the sheet will ask for a password. If he entered correctly, then he will be able to see the grades.

How can I implement this?
I tried using "hide" and ";;;" format for sells. And set password protection for the cell. using "allow user edit range" but when user enter the range password everything in the cell just go away.

Is there anyway to do this using a VBA? I tried some codes but does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: pretty sure this is not possible. [Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lock-cells-in-a-worksheet-HA010342979.aspx) Hiding the cell and revealing it as they click the cell doesn't seem to exist as a function.

Comment: I feel like it would be more secure to have an Excel function/VBA script that loops through the list, creating a new worksheet for each student and emailing only their result(s).

Comment: Yes, this is possible via VBA. It'd be much easier in pretty much any other medium, this is a huge request. Not to mention you'd have to lock the VBA code otherwise students would be able to view the passwords for others..

Comment: This page is probably going to give you most of the tools you need to get something working: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb268022(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: It would probably be easier to extract the grades and send them to each student individually.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments that having a master workbook that emails individual sheets to students would be a sensible approach, Excel isn't designed to be that secure.

Having said that, if really pressed and if I had control over the passwords, I'd keep the data in hidden sheets one-way encrypted. So you have to know the password to see the data.